# Spring Data: Page information missing fron response on using CollectionModel with RepositoryRestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

My repository method is:

```
public Page<Order> findByStatusIn(List<OrderStatus> orderStatuses, Pageable pageable);
```

Which is called from Controller (`@RepositoryRestController`) as :

```
Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"id"));
Page<Order> myOrders = orderRepository.findByStatusIn(orderStatuses, paging);
```

The Page is converted to `CollectionModel`:

```
CollectionModel<Order> resources = CollectionModel.of(myOrders);
resources.add(linkTo(methodOn(OrderController.class).userOrders(page,pageSize,currentUser)).withSelfRel());
return new ResponseEntity<>(resources,HttpStatus.OK);
```

The output json is like:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
"orders": [
  {
  "orderId": 10011,
    "createdAt": "2022-05-18T16:28:19+05:30",
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2022-06-10T16:28:15+05:30",
    "createdBy": "User01",
    "status": "PENDING"
  },
  {
  "orderId": 10012,
    "createdAt": "2017-05-03T14:28:19+05:30",
    "lastUpdatedAt": "2022-06-10T16:28:15+05:30",
    "createdBy": "User01",
    "status": "SHIPPED"
  }
]
  },
"_links": {
"self": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/orders/userOrders?page=0&pageSize=11"
}
}
}
```

The data I got is correct but the response is missing the Page information as from the response getting from repository methods in Spring data.
ie, the section like

```
"page": {
"size": 20,
"totalElements": 20,
"totalPages": 1,
"number": 0
}
```

is missing.

How the page information can be added to the response when `@RepositoryRestController` is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PagedModel`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/PagedModel.html) should be used to create representations of pageable collections, instead of `CollectionModel`. To easily convert `Page` instances into `PagedModel` use [`PagedResourcesAssembler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/PagedResourcesAssembler.html) as described [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/hateoas/pagination-links/).